# How to format the color of a cell based on the time in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with employees scheduled hours in column B in the form 9-5, 8:3-12:30, etc.  I then have a row at the top of the sheet that sections off the day by hour blocks that the store is open in the form of 7-8, 8-9, etc.  What I would like to do is shade all the cells that an employee is scheduled to be at work based on the time that I have entered in column B.  For example, if Tony is scheduled 9-11 in cell B6, I want cells F6 (representing the hours 9-10) and G6 (representing the hours 10-11) to highlight red.  Thanks!

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you have a recent version of Office it might do it.  Press F1 in excel but please don't put me in cell B6. I have a get out jail free card.and diplomatic immunity ;)

Answer (score 0):

I "developed" a method while I was doing MPM diagrams, which is pretty similar to your task:

To be able to handle the hours in an easier way, you should do **two steps before starting**:

1. Put the starting hour in column B, and the finishing hour to column C (with your example: for Tony B6 cell contains "9", C6 cell contains "11")
2. For the top row also use single number instead of interval (F6 contains "9" - which represents the working-hour starting at "9", G6 contains "10")

Now for the **conditional formatting**:

1. You can put this formula in cell D6, then copy it through the row-6 - it will give you "1" in cells which are Tony's working hours, and put 0 in the rest of the cells:

> =IF(AND($B3<=D2,$C3>=E2),1,0)

2. Now all you have to do is Conditional Formatting, set two rules for the whole area:

   - If value equal to "1", then set background color red and also the font color red
   - If value equal to "0", then set background color white and also the font color white

Probably it's not the most elegant way, but it works.